# Javascript Owl carousel, how can I set dynamically autoplayTimeout field from API?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Is it possible to set owl carousel dynamically field autoplayTimeout? Im fetching data from api.

$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
url:
"url?api_token=",
method: "GET",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
reklame = data.data;

```
  let content = "";

  let tip;
  for (i = 0; i < reklame.length; i++) {
    if (reklame[i].type == "video") {
      content += `<div class="reklamaVideo"><video
        class="video"
        autoplay
        loop
        muted
        poster="/img/load.gif"
        preload="auto"
      >
        <source src="amazonUrl" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="amazonUrl" type="video/ogg" />
      </video></div>`;
    } else if (reklame[i].type == "image") {
      content += `<div class="reklamaSlika"><img src="amozonUrl"></div>`;
    }
  }

  console.log(content);

  console.log(reklame);
  var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
  owl.html(content);

  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    margin: 0,
    autoplay: true,
    video: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 10000,
  });
},
```

});

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Any input how can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: I just added code

Comment: do you have a working example ?

Comment: I managed to solve it, thanks anyway!

Comment: Would be great if you answer the question for people who have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
  let content = "";
  let timings = [];
  for (i = 0; i < reklame.length; i++) {
    if (reklame[i].type == "video") {
      content += `<div class="reklamaVideo"><video
        class="video"
        autoplay
        loop
        muted
        poster="/img/load.gif"
        preload="auto"
      >
        <source src="{reklame[i].file_path}" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="{reklame[i].file_path}" type="video/ogg" />
      </video></div>`;
      timings.push(reklame[i].seconds* 1000);
    } else if (reklame[i].type == "image") {
      content += `<div class="reklamaSlika"><img src="{reklame[i].file_path}"></div>`;
      timings.push(reklame[i].seconds* 1000);
    }
  }

  var owl = $(".reklameOwl"); 
  owl.html(content);
  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    margin: 0,
    loop: true,
    onChange: callBack,
  });

  var currentTimeout = null;
  var i = 0;
  var time = 0;
  function callBack(event) {
    var videos = document.getElementsByClassName("video");
    for (let video of videos) {
      video.currentTime = 0;
    }
    if (currentTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
    }
    if (i + 1 == timings.length) {
      time = timings[0];
    } else {
      time = timings[i + 1];
    }
    if (i + 1 == timings.length) {
      i = 0;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
    currentTimeout = dynamicTimeout(time);
  }

  function dynamicTimeout(time) {
    return setTimeout(function () {
      clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
      owl.trigger("next.owl.carousel");
    }, time);
  }
```